# Why Can't I communicate with my server?

Tags: java, android, python, sockets

I have been trying to make a client project on Android Studio that will connect to a server that I made in Python (Pycharm). As for the IP used, I entered at the server the local host and in the client the IPV4 of the computer's server.
The debugging was made through the phone itself and not the emulator.

When I tried running the code and connect to the server through out the ipv4 with the same port, I got connection timed out. 
At the moment, the debugger is stuck on the client class while trying to get a message from the server, the - "while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer))" - line  while on the server, the code did not recieve any message from the client and thus its stuck on receiving.

How do I solve this issue?

Client code:  - Where the connection occurs

```
public class RequestAndAnswer extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
private String dstAddress,result1;
private int dstPort;
private String response = "";
private String out;


RequestAndAnswer(String output)
{
    dstAddress = "1.5.0.66"; //fake ipv4
    out= output;
    dstPort= 8886;

}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

    Socket socket = null;

    try {
        socket = new Socket(dstAddress, dstPort);

     //send out to server
        DataOutputStream DOS = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        DOS.writeUTF(out);

        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(1024);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

        int bytesRead;
        InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();


        while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            byteArrayOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            response += byteArrayOutputStream.toString("UTF-8");
        }

    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        response = "UnknownHostException: " + e.toString();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        response = "IOException: " + e.toString();
    } finally {
        if (socket != null) {
            try {
                socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

The main code:

```
public void onClick(View v)
{
    if(v == loginButton)
    {

        String userNameString =  userName.getText().toString();
        String passwordString = password.getText().toString();

        String output ="100"+
        intToString(userNameString.length())
        +userNameString 
        + intToString(passwordString.length())
        +passwordString;

        RequestAndAnswer myClient = new RequestAndAnswer(output);

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
            myClient.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
        else
            myClient.execute();

        String answer="";

        do {
            answer = myClient.getResult();   /**In order to make sure that I
                                              will get my response after the
                                              communication started between
                                              the server and the client **/
        }
        while(answer.matches(""));


        if(answer.matches("1100"))
        {
            Intent i = new  Intent(this,Computer_choosing_selection_activity.class);
            i.putExtra("username",userNameString);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
        else if(answer.matches("1101"))
            {
            String error = "The username and password do not match";
            errorText.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            errorText.setText(error);
        }
        else
        {
            String error = "Could not connect";
            errorText.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            errorText.setText(error);
        }

    }
```

The AndroidManifest.XML includes the following lines -

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

The server code: - In python

```
import socket
import sys

HOST = '127.0.0.1'   # Symbolic name, meaning all available interfaces
PORT = 8886 # Arbitrary non-privileged port

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print 'Socket created'

#Bind socket to local host and port
try:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
except socket.error as msg:
    print 'Bind failed. Error Code : ' + str(msg[0]) + ' Message ' + msg[1]
    sys.exit()

print 'Socket bind complete'

#Start listening on socket
s.listen(10)
print 'Socket now listening'

#now keep talking with the client
while 1:
    #wait to accept a connection - blocking call
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print 'Connected with ' + addr[0] + ':' + str(addr[1])
    data = s.recv(1024)
    number = data.substr(0,3)

    if(number == "100"):
        data = data[4:]
        len=data[0:3]
        data=data[2:]
        name = data[:int(len)]
        data = data[int(len):]
        len=data[0:3]
        data=data[2:]
        password = data[:int(len)]
        if((name == "Tod") and (password == "Aa123456")):
            conn.send("1100")
        else:
            conn.send("1101")

s.close()
```

EDIT:
I changed in the server the address to the IPV4 instead of the local 127.0.0.1 and I managed to connect although it gave me the following error before hand

"Socket.error: [Errno 10057] request to send or receive data was denied because the component is not connected to the socket and provided an address (when sending data socket unit via a call to sendto)"

after this message I got an output of"connected" and the program shut down.

Comment: Start debugging step by step. I were you, I would have started by checking the firewalls of my server.  Then would have checked whether request is received on the server by using `tcpdump`

Comment: this `HOST = '127.0.0.1'   # Symbolic name, meaning all available interfaces` is your original code?... because it ain't mean what the comment says. If you already check what @MoinuddinQuadri said, I think this is the main issue. I can explain more if you say that line is actually your original code.

Comment: Actually @RafaelAguilar the connection itself isn't a part that I made by myself. It's more.. .borrowed.